# How Come This Website Is Not Suffering From Duplicate Content Issues?

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content, url-rewriting

If you visit the following website

http://onedesigncompany.com/

and scroll down then you'll notice that the URL is being changed in the address bar. So, isn't it a duplicate content issue?

Is not multiple URLs pointing to the same page with exactly same content?

How come it is not suffering from duplicate content issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this off-topic? Isn't this an issue?